# lazy load images loads the all images on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, jquery-lazyload

I'm using [bttrlazyloading](http://bttrlazyloading.julienrenaux.fr/) plugin to lazy load all my images on my page.
I have a list with divs and inside each div there is an image.

My content is dynamic and using template (html) i clone the div depending on how much elements i need.

this is my code:

```
    $.each ( THIS.get('content').topics, function(i, topic){
                $('.topic_list').append($('#topic_item').clone(true).attr('id','topic_item'+i));
                $('#topic_item'+i).find('.topic_image').attr('id', 'topic_image_'+i);
                $('#topic_image_'+i).attr('data-bttrlazyloading-xs-src', topic.icons.high_res_icon_180x180);
                $('#topic_image_'+i).attr('data-bttrlazyloading-sm-src', topic.icons.high_res_icon_180x180);
                $('#topic_image_'+i).attr('data-bttrlazyloading-md-src', topic.icons.high_res_icon_360x360);
                $('#topic_image_'+i).attr('data-bttrlazyloading-lg-src', topic.icons.high_res_icon_360x360);
});
```

when i finish to build my page i'm callin the plugin:

```
$('.topic_image').bttrlazyloading({
            backgroundcolor: 'transparent',
            animation: 'fadeInUp',
            event: 'scroll'
        })
```

The images are not shown until i scroll to them, my problem is that the icons are all loaded at once even when you still can not see them.

I can see that on the network.

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 2):

can't believe.. after a lot of hours.. i was missing `<!DOCTYPE html>`